# Nginx alter path links are relative to?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a location setup in my Nginx config file as below, it works ok however relative links in the page (css, scripts, anchor tags) aren't relative to the location /os and instead are realtive to the hostname / ip address. How can I append /os before the path?

```
location /os {
    rewrite /os(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.125/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the `rewrite` statement? It look like you're stripping the /os prefix from the path in that line

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I gave it a try but all relative links on the page still relate to https://192.168.0.125/ instead of https://192.168.0.125/os